# SDL2-image won't load textures (but surfaces work) and i don't get any error message

Tags: c++, sdl-2, mingw-w64, sdl-image

i am making a game using SDL2, using IMG_LoadTexture() to load images, and it works fine on my main computer, but i recently acquired a new laptop, and the same code on this new machine won't load textures, but SDL doesn't give me any error message.

- IMG_LoadTexture() returns null
- IMG_GetError() and SDL_GetError() give me nothing (which is weird, since IMG_LoadTexture() returning null means an error occured)
- Loading surfaces (IMG_Load()) works
- I work on msys2/mingw64 and launch the executable from the MSYS2/MINGW64 shell, checked for zlip and libpng, everything is here
- Checked SDL initialization, `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK)` returns 0 (no error), `IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG)` returns 3 (no error), same outputs as on the other computer where everything works.
- Happens with all tested image formats (png, jpg, bmp)

[image: The code]

does anyone have any idea about what could be the cause of such a situation ? In the mingw install or something ?

#### Reproducing this

Here are the steps that led to the situation :

- Install msys from the [official website](https://www.msys2.org/)
- install the following libraries using pacman :

  - base
  - make
  - mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
  - mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2
  - mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_image
- Compile the following program :

  ```
  #include "SDL2/SDL.h"
  #include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"
  #include "SDL2/SDL_syswm.h"
  #include <iostream>    
  int main(int argc, char** argv){

      int res = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK);

      std::cout << res << '\n';
      if ( res < 0){
          printf("Couldn't initialize SDL (%d): %s\n", res, SDL_GetError());
          exit(1);
      }

      res = IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG);

      std::cout << res << '\n';
      if (res < 0) {
          printf("Couldn't initialize SDL Image (%d): %s\n", res, IMG_GetError());
          exit(1);    
      };

      int rendererFlags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
      int windowFlags = 0;

      SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("KuriX", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600, windowFlags);

      if (!window){
          printf("Failed to open %d x %d window: %s\n", 800, 600, SDL_GetError());
          exit(1);
      }

      SDL_SysWMinfo win_info;

      SDL_VERSION(&win_info.version);
      SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &win_info);

      SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "linear");

      SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, rendererFlags);

      if (!renderer){
          printf("Failed to create renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
          exit(1);
      }

      SDL_Texture* t = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "JPGTest.jpg");
      std::cout << t << '\n';

      if (t == NULL){
          std::cerr << "Error ! Message : " << IMG_GetError() << '\n';
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- compile/link with

  ```
  g++ testSDL.cpp -o out.exe `sdl2-config --cflags --static-libs` -Wall -g -std=gnu++2a -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lSDL2_image -lm
  ```

  Output :

  ```
  0
  3 
  0
  Error ! Message :
  ```

Keep in mind that the same code, using the same libraries, works fine on my main computer, and all previous computers i used previously. Something must have went wrong with the installation on the new laptop, but i just don't see what.

Comment: We'll need a [mcve]. What does `IMG_Init` return? How do you start your app, from MSYS2 shell or not?

Comment: I added these informations to the question

Comment: What flags were passed to `IMG_Init()`? Does it return the exact same flags? And still need a [mcve].

Comment: added that as well
i don't really see how i can do a reproducible example here tho, since the problem is that the (seemingly) exact same thing works just fine on all other computers i've built this project on. I'm going to add a "reproduce it" section, but i don't think it's very relevant here

Comment: Sometimes buggy code can work on some machines, and break on others. Not sure if the problem is with the code or not, but checking doesn't hurt.

Comment: Another thing to check is the list of loaded dlls using `ntldd -R my_program.exe`. Run it on your development machine, and distribute with your app all the dlls that it lists (ignoring those that are not distributed with MSYS2 or SDL).

Comment: Your whole repo is not "minimal". Ideally it should be a small single-file program, embedded in the question itself as text (lone links are usually frowned upon, since they might rot eventually).

Comment: I added a simple program that fails just like my project

Comment: Your new code doesn't call `IMG_LoadTexture`. Please actually try to call it from this new code, on both machines.

Comment: Your statement _"SDL doesn't want to link one-file programs for some reason"_ is a red flag. You have apparently worked around some kind of linker error by adding another source file. That makes no sense. It's anybody's guess as to what linker error you had, but perhaps you should show it.

Comment: It was the classic "undefined reference to SDL_Main", since it's not relevant to the current question at all i just took the first workaround that came to mind.